# Remote rsnapshot failing with "Permission denied" error

Tags: permissions, backup, rsync, rsnapshot

I'm trying to set up remote backups with rsnapshot from my home server. I want my server to connect into my laptop and take backups over SSH.Everything is set up correctly and I can connect from my server to the laptop perfectly.

The problem is I'm getting a permission error when I run `sudo rsnapshot -v hourly` (from the server):

```
...
rsync: opendir "/foo/bar" failed: Permission denied (13)
...
```

I've created a separate `backup` user on my laptop and I'm connecting over ssh with this user. This is my `~/.ssh/config` that rsnapshot is making use of:

```
Host macbookpro
    HostName macbookpro
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    User backup
    Identity File ~/.ssh/keys/macbookpro.id_rsa
```

I've also added the following to my sudoers file on my laptop which should allow rsync to run as root when called remotely by rsnapshot:

```
backup  ALL=(root)      NOPASSWD:       /usr/bin/rsync
```

yet whenever I run rsnapshot I continue to get permission errors. Does anyone see what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like I figured it out. Poking around on my laptop, I tried to run the `rsync` command (that `rsnapshot` would normally invoke over ssh) manually as the `backup` user and noticed I was getting permission errors locally as well.

It seems that even if you have the entry in your sudoers file to explicitly allow a user run a certain binary without a password, you still need to actually preface your command with `sudo`. (I'm on a macbook so I'm not sure if this is particular to OSX)

There didn't seem to be a good way to do this in `rsnapshot.conf` so I followed the instructions in [this tutorial](http://technokracy.net/2011/01/07/root_sudo_rsnapshot/)

I made a file on my laptop called `rsync_sudo.sh` and added the following:

```
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/rsync "$@";
```

then symlinked it to `/usr/bin/` and back on my server I added the following to `/etc/rsnapshot.conf`:

```
rsync_long_args         --rsync-path=rsync_sudo.sh --delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded
```

and now everything seems to be working

Comment: Didn't really resolve it for me. Same rights issues are coming up all over the place.